# MySQL bodge job copy table

Tags: mysql

Like always, this is probably an easy one that I have overseen while browsing for the solution.

I have the following query:

```
' INSERT INTO '.$this->ticket_attachment_table.' (SELECT * FROM '.$this->email_attachment_table.' WHERE emailId = '.mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']).');'
```

this just copies the items out of one table and into the other.

However this usually works fine when the table is a complete duplicate, however this one has one different field name.

So, say all the field titles are the same, except in one table the field headings for the same field are messageId and emailId, can I incorporate a kind of `messageId AS emailId` somewhere in this same query?

Comment: you'd have to list the full field set in the select, plus aliases to translate the fields that have different names, so `select f1,f2,f3 AS newf3,...` instead of `select *`. that or you temporarily add the 'wrong' field name to the target table and then do some `alter` manipulations afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ::

```
Insert into table1 (column11, column12, column13....)  
Select column21, column22, column23... from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

A different field name should not impact your query at all. As long as the order of fields/types are the same, the query will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Insert into Table (Fieldname,Fieldname,Fieldname,..) Select ...
```

Actually Judy is correct, the above is useful when the fields are in different orders.